# #Name Error in Excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns  ED and EE. They only contain yes or no values.  if ED is Yes and EE is No then my column is Yes. Likewise if EE is Yes and ED is No then No, if both are No then I would like BLANK " " . Here is what I have.

```
=IF(AND(ED2=”Yes”,EE2=”No”),”Yes”,IF(AND(ED2=”No”,EE2=”Yes”),”No”, ” ”))
```

It says I am getting a #Name error. There is no typos of any functions, I changed both ED & EE columns to text, I made sure all my quotations were as they are suppose to be and I am still getting the error.  Help?

Comment: the issue is the `”` it is not the proper `"`

Comment: How did I get the other quotes versus those? Is it copy pasting

Comment: You have a stylized version of the `"`  This usually happens when the formula is copy and pasted in or through another text editor like Word.  If you find the ascii code for it is 148 where the ascii code for '"' is 34.  Some times this is put in intentionally by websites to keep the average user from simple copy and paste.

Comment: Fundamentally @ScottCraner is right, but it's not an ASCII character. ASCII doesn't have a code 148. It's in various ASCII extensions, some of which may have it at code 148, such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Thank you I will have to keep track of this as I copy paste between spreadsheets and word documents. I was not aware of this and had been ripping my hair out haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just swapped out the quotation marks and it worked for me

```
=IF(AND(ED2="Yes",EE2="No"),"Yes",IF(AND(ED21="No",EE2="Yes"),"No", ""))
```

If that still doesn't work, try the evaluate formula button

Comment: I am so angry right now. I did this twice. What kind of quotations did I have?

Comment: I think Scott might be able to answer that better then I would